# open source marching cubes algorithm in c++?

Tags: c++, marching-cubes

i am trying to use marching cubes to visualize molecular densities and i was wondering if there was a place on the web that has a open source libraries to do this. i have seen many people post their code online, but i don't want to "steal" code.

i know i can email them and ask for permission, which i might end up doing, but i was wondering if there was a LAPACK type library for computer graphics which would have a marching cubes routine which i could just link against.

by this i mean that LAPACK simply has functions which do a predetermined linear algebra calculation and it is very common for people to simply link to LAPACk (or something like it) instead of writing their own code from scratch.

is there a package or library like this for marching cubes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at VTK open source library. I used to use that before:

[vtkMarchingCubes Class Reference](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a01703.html)

Comment: thanks, i'm a bit confused as to how that works though. i see that i can #include the given header, but where do i go to download the library and how should i link to it?